# Google Maps Navigation Android with sights

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, navigation, maps

I want to open Google Maps to navigate from point A to B. Over some other points. And it should show me near sights.

This is how i start the intent right now:

```
Intent navigation = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri //saddr=46.625799, 14.312887 &daddr=46.623510, 14.300612 &mode=bicycling &restaurants
                    .parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=46.625799, 14.312887 &daddr=46.623510, 14.300612 &mode=bicycling &q=restaurants" ));
startActivity(navigation);
```

But it doesn't show me the nearby restaurants... 
I mean I don't want restaurants I want sight but I have no idea what I should write instead of restaurants...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call a different API for it. First, sights can be a bit vague, Places API however have different [supported Places Types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) that you can pick which will match with what you intend to have.

In terms of actual search, you can look at how to call [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search). Just set the optional parameter `type` and you're good to go.